# javascript validation after dust template renders

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have been able to load the page using dust template but I have go give some kind of validation to the forms. How do I add the validation ?

Do I need to use Dust Helper method only ?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to use a Dust Helper to validate a form however it could be an option but not necessarily a common solution. You can do it simply in your JavaScript after you render the page.

Here is a simple example:

```js
dust.render('myTemplate', json, function(err, out){
  // generating the html here
  $('#my-form').on('submit', validateForm);
});

function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // validation logic goes here
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <form action="action.php" method="post" id="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Monshi for the response but I have some dynamic content that I am loading through dust. I think the problem is the event reinitialize after the ajax. I had put the function to reinitialize and it does goes back to the function but doesn't invoke any funtion.